# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Razor Page: return same page on post

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page with a List model that iterates over the list and displays model data. I have a button called "Delete" that deletes the item from the database based on the id. This part works ok. After deleting an item, I would like to stay on the same page with updated model list. How do I accomplish this? Right now, I "return Page()" from the understanding that this just refreshes the page. This just returns an empty page with no data in it.

UserList.cshtml:

```
@page
@model UserListModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>User Roles</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>                
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model.UsersListModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                <td>@user.LastName</td>
                <td>@user.Email</td>                    
                <td>                        
                    <form method="post">                            
                        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-userId="@user.Id" value="Delete User" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the user?');"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UserList.cshtml.cs:

```
public List<UserViewModel> UsersListModel { get; private set; } = new List<UserViewModel>();
        
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var users = await _userService.GetUsers.ToListAsync();
            var userViewModel = new List<UserViewModel>();
            foreach (ApplicationUser user in users)
            {
                var thisViewModel = new UserViewModel();
                thisViewModel.UserId = user.Id;
                thisViewModel.Email = user.Email;
                thisViewModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                thisViewModel.LastName = user.LastName;                
                userModel.Add(thisViewModel);
            }
            UsersListModel = userViewModel;
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(string userId)
        {           
            
            var result = await _userService.Delete(userId);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred deleting user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }            
            return Page(); // I would like to stay on the same page with the updated list of users.
            

        }
```

Comment: You must update `UsersListModel` just as you do in `Get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `return Page()` directly at the end of the Post method, because the Post method execution ends you are not getting data from the database.
You can call back your Get method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(string userId)
{           
            
    var result = await _userService.Delete(userId);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred deleting user with ID '{userId}'.");
    }            
    return RedirectToPage("./UserList");        
}
```